# Union Select Distinct syntax?

Tags: t-sql

I have a huge table that contains both shipping address information and billing address information. I can get unique shipping and billing addresses in two separate tables with the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ShipToName, ShipToAddress1, ShipToAddress2, ShipToAddress3, ShipToCity, ShipToZipCode
FROM Orders
ORDER BY Orders.ShipToName

SELECT DISTINCT BillToName, BillToAddress1, BillToAddress2, BillToAddress3, BillToCity, BillToZipCode
FROM Orders
ORDER BY Orders.BillToName
```

How can I get the distinct intersection of the two? I am unsure of the syntax.

Comment: Since you accepted the UNION answer I assume you meant union not intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can join both sets on all fields and this will return the records that match:</strike>

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders o1
INNER JOIN Orders o2
    ON o1.ShipToName = o2.BillToName
    AND o1.ShipToAddress1 = o2.BillToAddress1
    AND o1.ShipToAddress2 = o2.BillToAddress2
    AND o1.ShipToAddress3 = o2.BillToAddress3 
    AND o1.ShipToCity = o2.BillToCity
    AND o1.ShipToZipCode = o2.BillToZipCode
```

Or you should be able to use INTERSECT:

```
SELECT ShipToName, ShipToAddress1, ShipToAddress2, ShipToAddress3, ShipToCity, ShipToZipCode
FROM Orders
INTERSECT
SELECT BillToName, BillToAddress1, BillToAddress2, BillToAddress3, BillToCity, BillToZipCode
FROM Orders
```

Or even a `UNION` query (`UNION` removes duplicates between two sets of data):

```
SELECT ShipToName, ShipToAddress1, ShipToAddress2, ShipToAddress3, ShipToCity, ShipToZipCode
FROM Orders
UNION 
SELECT BillToName, BillToAddress1, BillToAddress2, BillToAddress3, BillToCity, BillToZipCode
FROM Orders
```

Comment: That does not work as expected. Right now the two queries I posted earlier return tables of count 1687 and 805 respectively. The intersected table shows only 312 and has only the ship to columns. If I quickly look at the data I see many addresses (that are NOT duplicates) missing.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify, from the two tables returned above, I would like to return all unique ShipToName/BillToName, ShipAddress1/BillAddress1, ShipAddress2/BillAddress2, ShipAddresss3/BillAddress3, ShipToZipCode/BillToZipCode combinations.

Comment: @BBauer42 maybe you should post some sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    toname, addr1,  addr2,  addr3,  city,   zip
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
        ShipToName AS toName, 
        ShipToAddress1 AS addr1, 
        ShipToAddress2 AS addr2, 
        ShipToAddress3 AS addr3, 
        ShipToCity AS city, 
        ShipToZipCode AS zip
    FROM 
        Orders

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT 
    BillToName AS toName, 
    BillToAddress1 AS addr1, 
    BillToAddress2 AS addr2, 
    BillToAddress3 AS addr3, 
    BillToCity AS city, 
    BillToZipCode AS zip
    FROM 
        Orders) o
ORDER BY ToName
```

Answer (score 3):

You say "Intersection" but you accepted the Union answer so I guess you just want the `UNION DISTINCT`. No need for derived tables and the three `DISTINCT`. You can use the simple:

```
SELECT 
    ShipToName     AS Name, 
    ShipToAddress1 AS Address1, 
    ShipToAddress2 AS Address2, 
    ShipToAddress3 AS Address3, 
    ShipToCity     AS City, 
    ShipToZipCode  AS ZipCode
FROM 
    Orders

UNION                               --- UNION means UNION DISTINCT

SELECT  
    BillToName 
    BillToAddress1, 
    BillToAddress2,
    BillToAddress3,
    BillToCity,
    BillToZipCode
FROM 
    Orders 

ORDER BY
    Name ;
```

Comment: +1 I guess I should have left my answer since it included a `UNION` version. :)

Comment: @bluefeet You did? (I didn't check your edit) thoroughly. Please undelete.

Comment: Naaw, Its ok. The question was not clear so my answer had several different queries in it. `INNER JOIN`, `INTERSECT` and `UNION`.

Comment: @BBauer42 So, my answer is the same as the third query by bluefeet, who posted more than an hour ago. Please, unaccept this and accept that so I can delete my answer.

Comment: K, sorry for the confusion guys, when I posted the original question I copy/pasted the wrong TSQL as I had a number of statements I was trying.

Comment: @BBauer42 No need for apologies. We were happy to help you.